# Can't save data in mongodb by mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I know this sounds like a repetition to ask again this question, the reason i do it is that I've tried all answer given here but until now i still have not the solution. I don't know what is wrong with my code which is shown here. Thanks in advance!

```
var Product = require("../models/product");

var mongoose = require("mongoose");
mongoose.connect("localhost:27017/shopping");

var db = mongoose.connection;


    db
      .on("error", function (err) {
        console.log("Connection Error!!! this's some prompts: ");
        console.log(err);
    })
      .once("open", function () {
        console.log("Open DataBase Successfully!!!");
    });


var products = [
            new Product({
                imagePath: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/5/5e/Gothiccover.png',
                title: 'Gothic Video Game',
                description: 'Awesome Game!!!!!!',
                price: 10
            }),
            new Product({
                imagePath: 'http://cdn.addictinggames.com/newGames/game-links/must-a-mine-dupe-links/must-a-mine-dupe-links.png?c=17',
                title: 'Must a Mine',
                description: 'blablablabalbla lballdoi dfjflsjoid',
                price: 13
            }),
            new Product({
                imagePath: 'http://www.desktopwallpaperhd.net/wallpapers/8/7/halo-reach-wallpaper-background-desktop-games-title-81671.jpg',
                title: 'Halo reach, evolved, art, noble',
                description: 'Awesome Game!!!!!!',
                price: 20
            }),
            new Product({
                imagePath: 'http://www.qqxxzx.com/image-html.php?pic=/images/games-images/games-images-14.jpg',
                title: 'Girls on the Street',
                description: 'ldode doe odeedd lballdoi dfjflsjoid',
                price: 43
            }),
            new Product({
                imagePath: 'http://cdn.addictinggames.com/newGames/game-links/team-drift-cats-links/team-drift-cats-links.png?c=17',
                title: 'Team Drifts Card lives',
                description: 'magnifull Game!!!!!!',
                price: 22
            }),
            new Product({
                imagePath: 'https://lh3.ggpht.com/OoYWDD31U4GypmhoLAHAy7g9QfENitgoTGcFCC55jRS9wNXLk4Viutp5wJLFzOjgcg=h900',
                title: 'Car Race by Fun',
                description: 'dlfjdl gofioreo godiee joid',
                price: 18
            })
];

var done= 0;
for (var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
    products[i].save(function(err, result){
        done++;
        if(done === products.length)
            exit();
    });
}

function exit(){
    mongoose.disconnect();
}
```

Here is the model code:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var schema = new Schema({
  imagePath: {type: String, required: true},
  title: {type: String, required: true},
  description: {type: String, required: true},
  price: {type: Number, required: true}
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Product", schema);
```

Comment: can you post the model code

Comment: thk MigoFast, i've updated the post.

Comment: what actually happens? Do you get no errors, no console statements, nothing in the db at all?

Comment: Your code works - Made no changes just copy paste and it is populating a products collection in local mongodb - can you post the package dependencies

Comment: Check for errors: `products[i].save(function(err, result){ if(err) console.log(err);...`

Comment: the error says that ***Mongoose: mpromise (mongoose's default promise library) is deprecated***, nevertheless it saves the data

Comment: That is not an error, it is a warning that mongoose is showing, Is your data getting saved or not

Comment: thank you for your help! i understand now... as @ravishankar said it is just a warning. my data get saved.